# Why ordinal expression expected in if statement here

Tags: freepascal

I am trying to write a function which returns true if any character of sent line has ascii value > 127 (non-printable):

```
function isBinary(line: string): boolean; 
begin
    result := false; 
    for c in line do 
        if (Ord(c) > 127) then 
            result := true; 
        end; 
end;
```

However, it is giving error:

```
 Error: Ordinal expression expected
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What data types are `result` and `c`?

Comment: @Bogdan `Result` is clearly boolean, that's in the code

Comment: And `c`? What's his type?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan true. It was obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two mistakes in the code you show.

1. You do not declare the loop variable `c`. You need to do that, using the type appropriate to the prevailing `string` type in your code, which we cannot infer.
2. You have one `begin` statement in the code, but two `end` statements. That's one `end` too many.

Even when you fix this, this function does not test whether or not anything is binary. A `string` by definition holds text. And plenty of text can be encoded with ordinal values greater than 127.

Furthermore, the ASCII encoding uses values 0 to 127 inclusive, so "ascii value > 127" is something of a contradiction in terms.

Comment: I thought an `end` was needed for `if` statement.

Comment: No. You use `end` to pair with `begin`.

Comment: @rnso in Pascal you don't pair `end` with `if`.

Comment: Could he declare `c` as a global variable? The error message is type-related, not unknown identifier.

Comment: @BogdanDoicin A loop variable needs to be a local I believe

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** I am writing this answer not knowing the type of `c`.

Function [Ord](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/ord.html) has the following prototype:

`function Ord(X: TOrdinal):LongInt;`

This means it takes an ordinal type as a parameter. If `c` is type `char`, then the function works perfectly, but in your code you have an extra `end`, after the `if` clause.

The correct way to write the function is:

```
function isBinary(line: string): boolean; 
begin
    result := false; 
    for c in line do 
        if (Ord(c) > 127) then 
            result := true; 
end;
```

If `c` is not `char`, then the cause of the problem now becomes obvious.